# How to use interfaces properly in OOP languages

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I had this question for a long time but all the people who answered me didn't give me a proper answer. I think that the interfaces are used in OOP languages for polymorphism and in a situation like below I don't understand how to handle it,
[in java]

lets take following interface and two classes,

```
public interface Vehicle{
    public int noOfWheels();
    public String movingMethod();
}

public class Car implements Vehicle{
    public int noOfWheels(){
            return 4;
    }

    public String movingMethod(){
        return "Drive";
    }
}

public class Flight implements Vehicle{

    public int noOfWheels(){
        return 5;
    }

    public String movingMethod(){
        return "Fly";
    }

    //a behaviour only applicable to a flight
    public int noOfWings(){
        return 5;
    }
}


=======================================
simulation

    Vehicle v1 = new Car();
    System.out.println(v1.noOfWheels());
    System.out.println(v1.movingMethod);

    Vehicle v2 = new Flight();
    System.out.println(v2.noOfWheels());
    System.out.println(v2.movingMethod);
    System.out.println(v2.noOfWings());//this is not working as Vehicle interface doesn't have this method.
```

So, how can we achive the solution for a this kind of problem. I know that we can create another interface for flight types but
I took this example to express my problem.

Comment: You can use `instanceof` operator to check type of `v2` and cast it to concrete type `Flight`. Then you can use methods of `Flight` directly.

Comment: calling the noOfWings() method is gives errors as it is not declared in the Vehicle interface and as it is only applicable to a Flight I didn't put that method inside the Vehicle interface. I need to use all the vehicle types as Car object is used. I know that this is not possible. Is there a suitable pattern to achieve this.

Comment: 5 is an interesting number of wings btw.

Comment: This is called downcast: `((Flight) v2).noOfWings()`

Comment: What is the prbolem exactly? You can call `noOfWings()` as mention in the comment above. Any other problem apart from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% on what your problem is, but it seems like you're asking how you might express additional behavior to a base interface. It's worth knowing that an interface can extend another interface:

```
public interface Aircraft extends Vehicle {

    public int noOfWings();
}
```

A class that implements `Aircraft` will need to implement the methods declared by `Vehicle` as well as `noOfWings`.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your `Vehicle` class `noOfWings` method can also be defined as vehicle can have wings as well (e.g. flight) (Or you can extend `Vehicle` to create another interface)

Interfaces are used for polymorphism, but in your example there was no polymorphism for wings logically as well. You made it more specialized case for wings by defining it only in `Flight` class

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `v2` is a `Vehicle` and the compiler only allows calling methods from this interface. It appears that you understand this. If you want to call methods from the implementing class, you need to perform a cast.

With that said, I'm interested to know if you have encountered this problem in a real program? If so, can you describe what you encountered and why using an interface in this way is an issue?

Comment: actually this problem is not raised in a real program. I had this problem is since I learned some about of interfaces in OOP languages in my class.